# Move the data up when store in a database

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code, I am using the code to write data to input them in the database where I will move the data down from the same row as the other data.

Example:

```
================================================================
name  | start_date | stop_date | program_id | programme_title |
================================================================
channel 1                          3001       some name 1
channel 1                          3002       some name 2
channel 1                          3003       some name 3
```

Here is what it will move the program_id to the next row that go down:

```
================================================================
name  | start_date | stop_date | program_id | programme_title |
================================================================
channel 1                                     some name 1
channel 1                          3001       some name 2
channel 1                          3002       some name 3
```

This is the code I use:

```
def update_in_database(self):
     profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 'source.db'))
     conn = database.connect(profilePath)
     cur = conn.cursor()
     program_id = ''.join(str(x) for x in self.program_id)
     cur.execute('SELECT channel, program_id FROM programs')
     data = cur.fetchone()

     if data is not None:
         value = program_id
         for i in range(0,10):
             if value == program_id:
                 cur.execute("UPDATE programs set program_id=? WHERE program_id=?",('',value))
             else:
                 cur.execute("UPDATE programs set program_id=? WHERE program_id=?",(value-1,value))
             value = int(value) + 1
         cur.execute("SELECT channel , stop_date FROM programs WHERE program_id=?;",(value-2,))
         data = cur.fetchone()
         try:
             cur.execute("UPDATE programs set program_id=? WHERE channel=? and start_date=? ",(value-1,data[0],data[1]))
         except:
             pass
         conn.commit()
         conn.close()
```

I want to know how I can move the data up in the opposite than the code I use as I want to move the data up?

Example:

```
================================================================
name  | start_date | stop_date | program_id | programme_title |
================================================================
channel 1                                     some name 1
channel 1                          3001       some name 2
channel 1                          3002       some name 3
```

Here is what it will move the program_id to the next row that go up:

```
================================================================
name  | start_date | stop_date | program_id | programme_title |
================================================================
channel 1                          3001       some name 1
channel 1                          3002       some name 2
channel 1                          3003       some name 3
```

​​​​​​​
Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: I am sorry, but both "down" and "up" seem same to me! Check your Example "tables" please :)

Comment: I have already put the two different tables. One for the down and one for the up. Please check my question again.

Comment: @LAS I am using loops 10 times because I am using 10 buttons so i need to use loops 10 times. In which line that I need to change from - to +?

Comment: @Mark this updates 10 rows or program_ids.  Is that what you mean by button?

Comment: @Mark You're setting program_id from self instead of data.  What's the value of self.ProgramID?